# Advanced Python Code Assistance

Tags: python

I am trying to complete a Python code that counts each beat and places an X if its divisible by a number.

Example :

```
Divisions: 3
Divisible by: 2
Divisible by: 3
Divisible by: 4
Number of beats to print: 10
 1:
 2:X
 3: X
 4:X X
 5:
 6:XX
 7:
 8:X X
 9: X
10:X
```

You see how 2 is divisible by 2 so it prints an X on the first column? And 6 is divisible by both 2 and 3 so it prints an X on the first and second column? I need help doing that :)

This is my code so far, can anyone please complete it or help me complete it? I think i need to put the second loop inside another loop, because i need to loop over the numbers from 1 to c, working out for each beat whether it is divisible by each d (the numbers from list1). I probably need to make the loop increment b from 1 to c.

My Workaround :

```
list1 = []
a = int(input("Divisions: "))
for b in range(1,a+1):
  z = int(input("Divisible by: "))
  list1.append(z)
c = int(input("Number of beats to print: "))
for e in range(1,c+1):
  for d in list1:
    remainder = b%d
    if remainder == 0:
      print(" "+str(e)+":","X")
```

Comment: I don't understand what exactly you have problems with. Concerning the output in the lower loop, I'd use `"{}: {}".format(e, "X")` to format the string.

Comment: I want to try get my output the exact same as it should be in the first output example

Comment: Well, you need one line for each `e`, so the `print()` must be moved from the inner to the outer loop. You need to assemble the content of that line in the inner loop though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
divs = [int(input('Divisible by: ')) for _ in range(int(input('Divisions: ')))]
for beat in range(1, int(input('Number of beats to print: ')) + 1):
    print '%2d:%s' % (beat, ''.join(
        'X' if (beat % div) == 0 else ' ' for div in divs).rstrip())
```

Using the test case you provided:

```
Divisions: 3
Divisible by: 2
Divisible by: 3
Divisible by: 4
Number of beats to print: 10
 1:
 2:X
 3: X
 4:X X
 5:
 6:XX
 7:
 8:X X
 9: X
10:X
```

Comment: `Your code example # Enter your code for "Clap The Beat" here.
divs = [input('Divisible by: ') for _ in range(input('Divisions: '))]
for beat in range(1, input('Number of beats to print: ') + 1):
  print ('%2d:%s' % (beat, ''.join('X' if (beat % div) == 0 else ' ' for div in divs)))`

Gives me an error.

`TypeError: 'str' object cannot be interpreted as an integer`

Comment: Your output has an extra trailing newline character. What does that error mean when i try to mark it?

Comment: Dw man! I got it! I just needed to add some if and elif and else statements and i got it to work! thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = []
a = int(input("Divisions: "))
for b in range(1,a+1):
  z = int(input("Divisible by: "))
  list1.append(z)

c = int(input("Number of beats to print: "))

for e in range(1,c+1):
  print('%3d:'%(e), end='')
  string=''
  for d in list1:
    remainder = e%d
    if remainder == 0:
      string += 'X'
    else:
      string += ' '
  print(string.rstrip())
```

Comment: WOW! This code works! One problem though! It has whitespaces! How do you remove that? rstrip?? please tell me how to remove the whitespace? I am using python 3.x btw

Comment: Like if i were to input numbers, whitespaces will print out of some numbers that have no X's in them. and also i want to position the ":" its one space back. not 2 spaces in front of the edge

Comment: nvm i got the positioning of the ":" so its columned. all i need to do now is remove all whitespaces.

Comment: I still don't understand which whitespaces are you talking about, if you mean the leading whitespace of each number's line you just have to change '%3d' into '%2d' in the first call to print, but beware that doing so will break the formatting when the number of beats has more than 2 digits

Comment: I only need the 2 digits! :) I need help with the whitespaces now. ill give you a link of my problem :D http://i.imgur.com/QpQ53Oq.png

Comment: then you just have to change '%3d' into '%2d' in the first call to print

Comment: I did! But I'm talking about the space after the ":" Did you see my screenshot? I want to remove all the pink using rstrip or slice :D But i need your help to do so :)

Comment: Your output has an extra trailing newline character. What does that error mean when i try to mark it?

Comment: ahh, ok I just couldn't understand what you meant.. It should be working now